# Capture a picture recognize picture identity

Tags: google-goggles

The new apps appear on market recently,
they are using a camera apps to capture a picture(the apps name is not Google Goggles) then will recognize the picture identity, and pop up the identity of the picture's video and playing the video at the same time. what kind of this things? it's Google Goggles? or what else they are using ?

Goggle Goggles have any API for developer recognize their own database? i would like to develop a own Google Goggles, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there is no goggles api so far. however you could use some of the following services to recognise your own image database:

- http://www.kooaba.com/
- https://moodstocks.com/
- http://elipsear.com/

you could implement an image recognition app in some hours. have fun